# Issue with multiprocessing and Queues in python

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

i am looking into using the multiprocessing module in python and have more or less solved the multiprocessing part but have a problem with using and understanding the Queue functionality!

Here it is what i trying to do, the idea is to start a process with a tail to a file and the second process to execute a command on a server! Both processes are using pexpect to connect to the server and the goal is to catch the log lines when the second process executes the command.

I managed to start the 'tail -f' process and also to send the 'stop Client' command on the second process. I get the results from the tail process in queue1 but i never see the result from the second process in queue2! Have in mind that the command 'stop Client' is successful executed since i see on the server that the 'Client is stopped'.

I assume that i haven't yet understand how to handle the Queue with two different processes!

Any clue maybe what could be my fault thinking?

Thanks in adv.

```
def connectServer(que):                        # daemon
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh server1')
    child.expect(['(?i)Password'], timeout=20)
    child.sendline(password)
    child.expect([cmdprompt])
    print 'Connected successful'
    cmd = 'tail -f ...\n'
    child.sendline(cmd)
    child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=30)
    before = child.before
    child.sendline("exit")
    child.close()
    before = re.split('\r\n',before)
    del before[0]
    del before[-1]
    que.put(before)

def stopClient(que):                          # non-deamon
    ld = pexpect.spawn('ssh server1')
    ld.expect(['(?i)Password'], timeout=20)
    ld.sendline(password)
    ld.expect([cmdprompt])
    cmd = 'stop client'
    ld.sendline(cmd)
    ld.expect([cmdprompt], timeout=60)
    before = ld.before
    ld.sendline("exit")
    ld.close()
    before = re.split('\r\n',before)
    que.put(before)

queue1 = multiprocessing.Queue()
c = multiprocessing.Process(name='connectServer', target=connectServer, args=(queue1,))
c.daemon = True

queue2 = multiprocessing.Queue()
s = multiprocessing.Process(name='stopClient', target=stopClient, args=(queue2,))
s.daemon = False

c.start()
time.sleep(1)
s.start()

tmp = queue1.get()
received = '\r\n'.join(tmp)
print(received)

tmp = queue2.get()
received = '\r\n'.join(tmp)
print(received)

c.join()
s.join()
```

Comment: The use of Queue seems fine. Maybe `stopClient` never reaches the last line?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the line: ld.expect([cmdprompt], timeout=60) was making a problem so i changed it to ld.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT], timeout=60). Now it is working just fine. Thanks again